# Cross-Domain SQL Server Service Accounts

Tags: installation, domain

I am working on a project in which we wish to have SQL Servers in a test domain make use of accounts in a development domain so that we don’t have to manage multiple forests of accounts.

We’ve established a one-way trust so that the test domain trusts accounts from the dev domain.  We granted ‘log in as a service’ rights to a machine in the test domain for an account on the dev domain.  When we try to install SQL Server and use that account as the service account, the install fails.

Has anyone encountered this issue and is there a resolution?

Comment: What does the Event Log tell you when you try to start the MSSQL service?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an accounts permission issue.

There are several install logs and utilities that you could check that would help you identify the required permissions.

[Sql Server Fails if the setup account doesn't have rights](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2000257/sql-server-installation-fail-if-setup-account-not-have-some-user-right). This article also links to a utility to check the account rights.

The [installation log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15) may also be available to view and may give some hints as to why it is failing.

Have you tried the Windows Server Event logs?

Comment: Thanks, the error we are seeing is:  "Unable to return managed service account info about user Win32 Error code 1326" which is during the install of SQL"

Comment: these may help https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fc566914-4e52-4b91-b05a-b086fdc3883d/unable-to-create-a-managed-service-account-in-windows-server-2016?forum=winserversecurity and  https://sqlmate.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/managed-service-accounts-with-microsoft-sql-server-2012/